# Alternative representation for $B_{n,k}(1!,\dots,(n-k+1)!)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, combinatorics, reference-request, bell-numbers

Let $B_{n,k}$ be the [Exponential Bell Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Stirling_numbers_and_Bell_numbers) and $\hat {B}_{n,k}$ the [Ordinary Bell Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Ordinary_Bell_polynomials). One has the identity:
$$
B_{n,k}(0!,1!,\dots,(n-k)!)
=
|s(n,k)|,
$$
with $s(n,k)$ the [Stirling number of the first type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number_of_the_first_kind). I am however interested in $B_{n,k}(1!,2!,\dots,(n-k+1)!)$, note that this satisfies:
$$
B_{n,k}(1!,2!,\dots,(n-k+1)!)
=
\hat B_{n,k}(1,\dots,1),
$$
this seems like a very simple formula but I do not find any references linking this quantity to Sterling numbers, Bell numbers or any other type of numbers which I find odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the Lah numbers(number of partitions of $[n]$ into $[k]$ linearly ordered sets): $$\frac{n!}{k!}\binom{n-1}{k-1}.$$
Notice that the difference in between the signed Stirling and this ones is that one is a cyclic order and the other is a linear order. They differ by a factor of $k.$ Which is the shifting you want.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @HolyMonk Sure :).